# Media Controllers Not Showing Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Good day all,
Please i'm using videoview to play a local video file, and i attached the mediacontroller, video plays ok, but no matter the setting i use, the media controller doesn't show, when i touch the device screen:
My code below:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Preview);

        this.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn, WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);

        videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoPreView);

        mediaController = new MediaController(this, true);
        mediaController.SetAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.SetMediaController(mediaController);
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        videoView.Prepared += OnVideoPlayerPrepared;
        Play("MyVids/PreviewCourse.mp4");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
        videoView.Prepared -= OnVideoPlayerPrepared;
    }

    private void OnVideoPlayerPrepared(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mediaController.SetAnchorView(videoView);

        //show media controls for 3 seconds when video starts to play
        mediaController.Show(3000);
    }
```

And this is my axml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/videoPreView"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Note: My videos are 480 by 360 in dimension

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tested your code, can't reproduce your issue. The controller will be shown at first and then `VideoView` is focused.

Comment: Hi @GraceFeng-MSFT, what you are saying is that, it does display at your side?

Comment: Yes. It displayed well.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Thanks for your reply, i can't seem to display the media controllers on my video. Is there a way to develop custom media controls, i've searched, but what i'm getting is for android studio, can i get something for xamarin.android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well eventually, i had to create the buttons for pause/play, forward, and rewind manually.

```
player.pause();
player.play();
player.SeekTo(CurrentPosition + 5000); //for forward 5 secs
player.SeekTo(CurrentPosition - 5000) //to rewind
```

Didn't know it was that easy
For those who want to create there's manually